# Recover data from damaged DVD

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery

Im new to Linux. I need a software with GUI to recover data from scratched or damaged DVD .I can't find any software for this purpose. In Windows there is CD/DVD data recovery tool.I thought that dvd disaster can do that but I found that

"this is not a CD/DVD data recover utility that you can use after the disc damage occurs, it’s rather an application that you should run while the optical disc is fully read-able!"

(http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/10/best-optical-disk-data-recovery-app-for-ubuntu-linux/)

I want to recover data from damaged dvd.

Comment: Is there any software with gui?

Comment: Have a good look at what @Ron linked to.

Comment: In this Q&A you need to react to the input you get from commenter. If @Ron posts a link, please evaluate it and edit your question mentioning the linked question and explaining why it does suit you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using PhotoRec with your corrupt image file. It can recover a lot of file types, not just photos as the name may imply.

Reference [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17811](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17811/recover-files-from-corrupt-dvd)

PhotoRec download [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)